# Why isn't contents.xcworkspacedata being ignored?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, gitignore

In my `.gitignore` I have this line:

```
!*.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
```

But my `contents.xcworkspacedata` still shows up in the Github Desktop. More specifically this is the exact file that shows up:

```
Project Name/Project Name.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
```

So I thought that maybe I was already tracking `contents.xcworkspacedata` on git, so I tried to remove it by doing:

```
$ git rm --cached 'Project Name/Project Name.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata'
```

But I get the error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'Project Name/Project Name.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata' did not match any files
```

But I know `Project Name/Project Name.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata` does exist b/c I `cd`-ed into it

So my question is what do I need to do so `Project Name/Project Name.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata` doesn't show up in Git (b/c I don't want to accidentally add it to the version control)?

Answer (score 0):

Space in 'Project Name' is creating the problem.
Use 'Project\ Name'.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Don't think that's the issue. B/c when I do that I get `fatal: pathspec 'Project\ Name/Project\ Name.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata' did not match any files`

Answer (score 0):

Add `*.xcworkspace` to `.gitignore` instead.
And then remove index from cache and commit as you did.
I guess there is a mistake in your initial string `!*.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata`